# VBA R1C1 formula calculation with cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference, excel-r1c1-notation

```
ws2.Cells(87, col - 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-5]C[0]-'Another Sheet'!F89"
```

When I run the above code, the result would be, "=AW83- 'Another Sheet'!'F89", which returns an error because the ' between ! and F89. I tried to use " & " but it does not work this way. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix R1C1 and A1-notation in a formula. If you use `FormulaR1C1`, you have to provide all addressen in R1C1-notation. You can use `Application.ConvertFormula` to convert your `F89`:

```
dim r as range
set r = ws2.Cells(87, col - 2)
r.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-5]C[0]-" & _
      Application.ConvertFormula("'Another Sheet'!F89", xlA1, xlR1C1, , r)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but the result doesn't seem to refer to the correct cell - I got C113 instead of F89. Any idea why that happened?

Comment: Ok I got it- relative reference. Now it works. Thank you very much!